# IBM Websphere application server 7 JAX-WS client WSSE UsernameToken

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, wsse, usernametoken

I'm consuming web service using JAX-WS on IBM Websphere application server 7. Setting WS message level security while passing the SOAP Message. 
UsernameToken xmlns:wsu is not passed correctly to provider end. Is there any configuration need on WebSphere server?

SOAP Message printed in my app log,

wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="XXXX" **xmlns:wsu**="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"

Web Service Provider received SOAP Message,

wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="XXXX" **xmlns:wsse**="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"

Don't know how SOAP message WS Security header is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I found issue and resolved. Namespace of WSSE & WSU should apply correctly. 
WSSE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
WSU = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"